# Concisest way to handle undefined variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I have an object that I am creating that could potentially have undefined properties.

Is there a more concise way to set the property than what I am doing below:

```
var ruleObj = {
    factor: (ruleArray[2] ? ruleArray[2].trim() : null),
    resultElseTarget: (ruleArray[10] ? ruleArray[10].trim() : null)
}
```

Notice how I have to repeat the variable after the ternary operator twice. The reason I'm asking is that I've run into this same type of problem several times and it doesn't seem like the best way to handle it.

Comment: This doesn't go to conciseness exactly, but you should be aware your ternary turns `''` into null, but turns `' '` (whitespace) into `''`. If an empty string should always turn to null, then `(ruleArray[2] || '').trim() || null`

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a function that wraps another function to do nothing on `null` and `undefined` values:

```
const liftMaybe = f => x => x == null ? null : f(x);
```

Then you can define a `trim` that does nothing to `undefined`:

```
const trimMaybe = liftMaybe(x => x.trim());
```

and make use of it:

```
var ruleObj = {
    factor: trimMaybe(ruleArray[2]),
    resultElseTarget: trimMaybe(ruleArray[10]),
};
```

It differs from your original in its handling of empty strings, but I don’t know if that was intentional or if it’s even relevant.

Comment: I like this, but I would consider it fairly difficult to reason about if a person were to be skimming the code, since its a function that returns a function that returns a function that type coerces a ternary expression and is then used inside another function that is called at execution time. I would like to hear your opinion on it compared to my answer below, which in equivalent syntax would be `const trimMaybe = (rule) => { if (!rule) return null; return rule.trim() }`

Comment: @agm1984: It doesn’t type-coerce anything. `x == null` is idiomatic `x === null || x === undefined`. I intentionally chose it over a falsy check because the behaviour on empty strings seemed wrong (see JC Ford’s comment on the question).

Answer (score 0):

Conciseness is one thing but with Javascript the bigger concern is readability and type checking.

In your example, if the value of `ruleArray[2]` is a boolean then it'd evaluate to false and set factor to null. Maybe that's what you want but just looking at your example code right now, I'd assume your `ruleArray` contains bools and not potential undefines.

The better way is to write a function to do null check

EDIT: someone was faster than me :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436844/643084

EDIT2: the other answer is great but i'd like to just make a note. `null` should not be treated the same as `undefined` even though they evaluate the same most of the times.

Comment: `null should not be treated the same as undefined`, In respect to the OP's problem, how would you treat it differently?

Comment: i really dont know what his application needs. Just pointing out some best practices about null and undefined should not be treated the same. It's most likely his application doesn't care.

Comment: Your correct you have to be aware that undefined & null have different meanings.  But in this case trimming either null or undefined doesn't make sense.  I would even go further and say what about `NaN` `Infinity` `object` `Array`,  maybe a more concise  way is actually `typeof x === 'string'`..

Comment: @Keith: If the array should never contain those, there’s no need to worry about them. Let it throw instead of failing silently.

Answer (score 0):

Some things:

Since you're checking indexes, you'd need to make sure that you have a length of at least the size you want. Otherwise ruleArray[10] can throw you and out of range error.

Assuming you are certain that you have the right number of elements in your array, you can use this to check a var for undefined, this is common to check incoming arguments (say you had something like function ( arg1, arg2 ) ):

```
arg1 = arg1 || 'some_default';
```

In your case, again assuming your array is long enough:

```
factor: ( ruleArray[2] || 'some other default' );
```

(Why would you set it to null if that's what you are trying to avoid).

If you're wondering, "is there a way to access an index that doesn't exist and just return null", the answer is "maybe...but I wouldn't".

Note, if the value is indeed falsy (say, 0, '', or false), you may not get what you expect, in which case you'd want to check for something more explicit, like null.

I get a lot of use of out the terse "something = thisValIfNotFalsy || someOtherDefaultVal. Like anything though careful when and where, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```js
    var ruleArray = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    
    function formatRule(rule) {
        if (!rule) return null
        return rule.trim()
    }
    
    var ruleObj = {
        factor: formatRule(ruleArray[2]),
        resultElseTarget: formatRule(ruleArray[10])
    }
    
    console.log(ruleObj.factor)
    console.log(ruleObj.resultElseTarget)
```

We created a pure function that is tasked with producing either null or a trimmed value, which avoids duplicating this logic elsewhere.

Comment: Pardon me if this doesn't work exactly as is, I'm sure it must but I didn't test it. If rule.trim() evaluates to `falsy`, it will set the value to null.

Comment: `ruleArray[2].trim()` would throw error if `ruleArray[2]` is undefined, yes?

Comment: Make this into a snippet, and everyone can run it.. :)

Comment: Thanks, I just skilled up there. I didn't know that was native to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function pattern and set default parameter with AND `&&` operator when passing the parameter to check if variable is defined, if not set element value to `null`. You can include further checks to determine if variable is passed is a string.

```js
let ruleArray = [];

ruleArray[10] = "def ";

let ruleFn = (factor = null, resultElseTarget = null) => 
               ({factor, resultElseTarget});

let ruleObj = ruleFn(ruleArray[2] && ruleArray[2].trim()
              , ruleArray[10] && ruleArray[10].trim());

console.log(ruleObj, ruleObj.factor === null);
```

Comment: `"null"` isn’t the same as `null`.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, that is correct. Is that a significant departure from code at OP?

Comment: It is. OP’s code produces `null`. If one of the input strings can be `" null "`, the conditions become indistinguishable.

Comment: @Ryan See updated post. Set variable identifier to `null`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more concise way

So far all answers seem to assume your input is either a string or null / undefined.  For me I'd say the check for null / undefined is the wrong way round.  You can only call trim on a string, so why not check it's a string?.  It would also mean NaN / Numbers / Arrays etc, would not error.  I'm assuming what your wanting this function to do is trim a string if it's a string, so I would also say you should pass the original value if not a string.

Maybe that's what @zaftcoAgeiha meant when he talking about not treating null & undefined the same.

Anyway, here is an example.  Notice how numbers are still passed, but `hello` gets trimmed.

```js
const ruleArray = [];

ruleArray[2] = null;
ruleArray[5] = 7;
ruleArray[7] = 'Helllo ';

const trimIfString = (x) => typeof x === 'string' ? x.trim() : x;


var ruleObj = {
    factor: trimIfString(ruleArray[2]),
    resultElseTarget: trimIfString(ruleArray[5]),
    hello: trimIfString(ruleArray[7])
} 

console.log(ruleObj);
```